# SSIS Unknown character error

Tags: sql, sql-server, csv, ssis, character

We have an audit database that is built of attempted logins from one of our sites. We are getting a few cases where for whatever reason people are adding text that contains special characters. no program i use seems to understand what these characters are.

I have an SSIS package that pulls this table into a CSV file but it fails with the message:

> The data conversion for column "UserName" returned status value 4 and status text "Text was truncated or one or more characters had no match in the target code page"

Is there a SQL query I can run that will remove any unknown character?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for the reply Ash! the issue was that I didn't know what the character would be and SQL/SSIS didn't understand it(it wasn't even in the extended ASCII table!)

I figured out a way of doing it if anyone is interested!

```
SELECT REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(MAX),USERNAME), '?', '') FROM TABLENAME
```

As VARCHAR doesn't understand the character it replaces it with a ? the column is NVARCHAR which understands the character even though SQL cant display it, so if we convert it we can do an easy replace on ?

Answer (score 0):

You can use the REPLACE function, like so

```
declare @ash varchar (3) = 'ash'

select REPLACE(@ash,'s','') -- remove character 's'
```

Returns 'ah'

Obviously you will have to provide the characters you wish to remove.

Hope that helps,

Ash

Comment: Well that I did not know! Thanks for posting your solution Glenn.